# How can I compute the norm of $f_x(y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n y_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

> Let $x\in l^1$, we define a map $f_x(y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n y_n$ for $y\in l^\infty$. I need to show that $f_x$ defines a bounded linear functional on $l^\infty$ and I need to compute $||f_x||$.

My idea was the following:

Let me first prove that $f_x$ is a linear functional. Therefore take $x\in l^1$, so $$f_x:l^\infty\rightarrow l^\infty, y\mapsto \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n y_n$$ Now let $y,z\in l^\infty$ and $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in \Bbb{R}$, then $$f_x(\alpha_1 y+\alpha_2 z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n(\alpha_1 y_n+\alpha_2 z_n)=\alpha_1 f_x(y)+\alpha_2 f_x(z)$$ by using linearity. So indeed $f_x$ is linear. Now we remark that $f_x$ is continuous on $l^\infty$ and hence we can immediately deduce from a theorem that $f_x$ is bounded. So let me compute the operatornorm. For $y\in l^\infty$ with $||y||_\infty\leq 1$ we have $$||f_x(y)||=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n y_n|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|| y_n|\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n| ||y||_\infty\leq ||x||_1$$
Is this true until here?

Now I want to show that we have indeed equality here.
But I don't see how to pick my $y$ such that $||f_x(y)||=||x||_1$. My idea was to take $y=\frac{1}{x}$ but this only works if $x_n\neq 0$ for all $n$. Could maybe someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define $y$ as follows :$y_{n} :=sgn(x_{n}) $, where $sgn(z)=\frac{\lvert z\rvert} {z} $ for $z\neq 0$ and zero otherwise, remark that $y$ belongs to the unit sphere of $l^{\infty} $, now computing $f_{x} (y) =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lvert x_{n} \rvert $, so $f_{x} (y) =\lvert \lvert x\rvert \rvert_{1} $, since u already proved that
$\lvert \lvert f_{x} \rvert \rvert \leq 
\lvert \lvert x\rvert \rvert_{1}
$, we conclude that we have equality.

Comment: So would this mean that the rest of my proof is correct?

Comment: And why can't I take $y_n=1$ for all $n$?

Comment: @Overtherainbow we are looking for a unit  vector(of norm 1) whose image, will give use $\lvert \lvert x\rvert \rvert $, the image of the vector u proposed is $sum_{n\geq 1} x_{n} $, which doesn't give us the norm of x in general (except if $x_{n} >0$ which isn't verified always). Regarding the rest of the proof, yes it's correct. In general, to prove that an operator has norm equal to some positive number p(which is provd to be an upper bound of the norm) , we need to find a unit vector or a sequence of unit vectors, whose images equal or converge to p.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it, don't I want to find $y$ such that $||f_x(y)||=||x||_1$? And not that $f_x(y)=||x||_1$

Comment: The two statements are equivalent since f takes values in real or complex numbers, of course the second equality implies the first one, now if y satisfies the first one, u just need to replace y by y'=(|f(y) |/f(y)) y, then f(y') =|f(y) |.